# PHP OOP classes of store pattern

Tags: php, oop

I have a doubt about the design of a system to manage items of a store using OOP.
I created the abstract class Product that will have the attributes $name and $price. Later I created the class Smartphone that extends Product. Smartphone has the attributes $brand and $os. Later I created the class Computer that extends Product and has attributes $cpuFrequency and $ram. Now, if I want to create an object corresponding to the Nexus 5, for example, what i have to do?
Consider, for example, that this object will have

```
$name = "Nexus 5"
$price = "250"
$brand = "LG"
$os="Android"
$cpuFrequency "2.0"
$ram = "2".
```

Here an example of classes.

```
abstract class Product {
    private $name;
    private $price; 
    //more methods
}

class Smartphone extends Product{
    private $brand;
    private $os;    
}

class Computer extends Product {
    private $cpuFrequency;
    private $ram;   
}
```

Also considered that there may be Computer without $os and Smartphone without $ram. just one example: D

P.S. I know that smartphone is a computer. I did a bad example. Please think at Telephone and Computer. Telephone has $number and $operator. Now i want to create a Smartphone that is at the same time Telephone and Computer.

Thanks for all and sorry again for my english

Comment: you're going to end up with a zillion different classes, which is itself totally unusable/unmaintainable. a smartphone **IS** a computer that just happens to be able to make phone calls. just like a laptop is a computer that happens to be portable and has its screen/harddrive built-in.

Comment: You could split up the product and it's specification. This would allow you to not have to create a subclass for each new type.

Comment: You should make `Product` an interface, then implement it. a `Smartphone` should extend a `Phone` class and implement a `Computer` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a ProductProperties class like so:

```
class ProductProperties
{
    private properties = array();

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return this->properties;
    }

    public function addProperty($id, $value)
    {
        this->properties[$id] = $value;
    }

    public function getProperty($id)
    {
        return this->properties[$id];
    }
}

abstract class Product
{
    private $properties;
    //more methods

    public function __construct(ProductProperties $properties)
    {
        $this->properties = $properties;
    }
}
```

You could pass an object of class ProductProperties to any of your product and let it handle all properties related issues. This would make for a more flexible design, this way you don't need to subclass just because a product has a different set of properties. Remember subclassing is all about changing or adding behavior.

Comment: I started to write an answer, and then this popped up, so I had to edit mine and give credit here :D - this is, in practice, the best way to do it, especially if you map the ProductProperties->addProperty to a database using an ORM

Comment: @Jonathan that's exactly the way I've used it in many of my projects

Comment: Just last thing. Why i have to create a class that has only an array as attribute? Why i can't put this attribute (the array) directly in the class Product? However thanks for all, you are very exhaustive.

Comment: @user4304554 Think about flexibility and decoupling. At this point you may be getting the product properties from a Database, so you put all your logic to populate the properties array in the product class. Now your system needs to read product properties from a text file, you have to go and change or subclass your product class to read properties from a text file. Using a ProductProperties class you could have different classes reading properties from different sources, and then use dependency injection to pass the right type of properties to the Product, no need to change your product class

Comment: `Remember subclassing is all about changing or adding behavior.` is this always true ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you should write constructors to your classes in some way that "child" class initialize the super class, to keep everything consistent.

```
abstract class Product {
    private $name;
    private $price; 
    //more methods

    public __construct($name, $price){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price =$price;
    }
}

class Smartphone extends Product{
    private $brand;
    private $os;
    // default value to $os: like that, we can create a Smartphone whitout an os
    public __construct($name, $price, $brand, $os = null){
        parent::__construct($name, $price);
        $this->brand = $brand;
        $this->os =$os;
    }
}

class Computer extends Product {
    private $cpuFrequency;
    private $ram;
    // default value to $ram: with this, we can create a Computer whiout ram
    public __construct($name, $price, $frequency, $ram = null){
        parent::__construct($name, $price);
        $this->frequency = $frequency;
        $this->ram =$ram;
    }

}
```

Then, to create a *Computer*, you can do, for

```
$computer = new Computer('notBuiltToWindows', 560 , 2.0, 4);
```

or, to create the Nexus in your example:

```
$nexus = new Smartphone($name, $price, $frequency, $ram);
```

and, to create a smartphone whitout a ram

```
$nexus = new Smartphone($name, $price, $frequency);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, making too many classes can get confusing.

The idea is to create a class that can cover many different scenarios, without too much work.

For example, you could have a class `Pet`.  A dog is a pet, and so can a snake...  This doesnt mean you should make a `FourLegged` or `Nolegs` class.

Much like your products, you may have a `product` class that holds things common to all products.  You may even want to have a sub class called `electronics` that can cover everything from phones to computers.

You may have a `productType` attribute that says what kind of electronic it is (e.g phone), but ultimately, there won't be too much variation between individual electronics: TV's, smartphones and computers both have screen specs, a smartphone and computer have ram, cpu's etc.

Comment: From reading the question I would assume that the op knows how to create objects. To my understanding this question is about the design of his application.

Comment: Thank you.  I have ruby on the brain.  I re-read the question and you are correct.  I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it at work is a combination of most of the above answers:

1) You have a product class / object - this contains the generic things that any product will have - a name, a description, some pictures, etc

2) You have a sub-class which contain the product attributes (a product attribute class) - e.g. size, weight (not all products are physical, so not all have sizes or weights), price, number_of_ram_slots, cupFrequency.

We allow the attributes to be user-defined by using an ORM that maps the attributes to the database. This gets the best of both worlds due to php not being able to do multiple inheritance - technically a smartphone is both a computer and a telephone, but by doing it the above way, it doesn't matter, as each is simply a product and a set of user-defined attributes.

Essentially this is the same answer as @Edgar's implementation

Answer (score 0):

At the top level we create concepts, non tangible things. Things that are in theory and must be implement in order to be tangible.

```
// make product an interface, or in other words a concept. its not tangible,
// but instead its just a concept thus making it an interface
interface Product {
   public function getName();
   public function getPrice();
   public function getBrand();
}

// A computer is also a concept, thats implemented by many devices like a laptop, 
// SMARTPHONE, desktop, calculator, etc...
interface Computer {
    public function getRam();
    public function getFrequency();
    public function getOS();
}
```

The Phone logic:

```
// We can implement the concept of a Product here
// the phone is also a concept, implemented by home phones, 
// telephones and mobile phones so we make it abstract
abstract class Phone implements Product {
    private $name;        
    private $price;
    private $brand;

    function __construct ($name, $price, $brand) {
         $this->name  = $name;
         $this->price = $price; 
         $this->brand = $brand;
    }

   public function getName() {
       return $this->name;
   }

   public function getPrice() {
       return $this->price;
   }

   public function getBrand() {
       return $this->brand;
   }
}
```

The smart phone logic:

```
// Smartphone is another concept implemented by many devices like a Nexus 5,
// what makes this concept different from a Phone is that it doubles as a computer.
// so we extend the concept of a phone by implement the concept of a computer
// making the Phone 'smart'
abstract class Smartphone extends Phone implements Computer {
     private $os;
     private $frequency;
     private $ram;

     public function __construct ($name, $price, $brand, $os, $frequency, $ram) {
          parent::__construct($name, $price, $brand);

          $this->os        = $os;
          $this->frequency = $frequency;
          $this->ram       = $ram;
     }

    public function getRam() {
         return $this->ram;
    }
    public function getFrequency() {
         return $this->frequency;
    }
    public function getOS() {
         return $this->os;
    }
}
```

Finally we have a finished Concept, something feasible/tangible. The Nexus product.

```
// A Nexus implements the concept of a Smartphone.
// so now the Nexus is a Smartphone, Computer, Phone and a Product
class Nexus extends Smartphone {
      public function __construct ($version) {
           parent::__construct('Nexus '.$version, 250, 'LG', 'Android', '2.0', 2);
      }
}
```

Use:

```
  // all we do is specify the version of nexus we are using
  $nexus5 = new Nexus(5);
```